How do you deploy Firebase functions with Terraform?
Google's Firebase/Terraform documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/terraform/get-started doesn't seem to show how to deploy Cloud functions for Firebase.
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/discussions/1142
I think I am just missing the event_trigger / event_type.

Maybe it's not supported yet on Terraform? I took a look into the provider documentation, but I couldn't find that many Firebase related resources.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions would imply it would be some time before the provider could support it.

So if I'm to event from say a firestore row update, am I expected to make a log sink / pubsub instead? I'm not sure how to move forward here.

@MatthewSchuchard; Could you clarify your statement? Are that due to limited program. lang.-support right now? Cause missing API/SDK things, or cause the Terraform support for Firebase are already limited? Please share your thoughts, to help us out. As a user, not that into Terraform (but picked up knowledge about that, in the last couple of days), I'm not really sure about that you're trying to "hint".

@hendry: Did you make any findings in the last couple of weeks? I'm also interesting in this. I've found this: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/16995
I'm also looking into this, as I'd like triggers for functions like onWrite (Firestore) to be handled. I've looked a bit into the Eventarc triggers, but I'm not really sure how I can cook thinkgs together in Terraform, without ending up with a crazy amount of things to configure and manage, compared to a simple "firebase deploy" command.

I've found issue #16995 in hachicorp/terraform-provider-google.
Here keeyzar submitted a issue where event_trigger does not do, what he expects it to do. But there's a great example on how to use the "event_trigger" and "event_filter" for the Cloud Functions v2. He also shared his fix in the same issue.
I'm aware that it's not a Firebase Function, but, to be fair, a Firebase Function are just a Cloud Function with a few tweaks on top. Which, to be fair, are almost just a Cloud Run instance with a few extra tweaks on top of that, too .
All credits for below example goes to keeyzar.
resource "google_cloudfunctions2_function" "function_2nd_gen" {
  project     = var.project_id
  name        = "some-example"
  location    = "europe-west3

  event_trigger {
    event_type = "google.cloud.firestore.document.v1.written"
    trigger_region = eur3
    service_account_email = "service-account-with-editor-role(created-by-gcloud-cli-command)"
    event_filters = [
      {
        attribute = "database"
        value     = "(default)"
      },
      {
        attribute = "document"
        value     = "p_orders/{orderid}"
        operator = "match-path-pattern"
      }
    ]
  }

  build_config {
    runtime               = "java17"
    entry_point           = "functions.FirebaseFirestore"
    source {
      storage_source {
        bucket = google_storage_bucket.storage-bucket.name
        object = google_storage_bucket_object.function_2nd_gen_zip.name
      }
    }
  }

  service_config {
    all_traffic_on_latest_revision   = true
    ingress_settings                    = "ALLOW_ALL"
    available_memory                 = "256Mi"
    service_account_email            = "service-account-with-editor-role(created-by-gcloud-cli-command)"
    available_cpu                         = 1
  }
}

Maybe that fits your needs? I've not tested the solution, but the event type does match up with the one in the documentation for Cloud Firestore Event types.
